# Transaction declined PancakeSwap Smart Router V3

Tags: javascript, python, web3py, uniswap, pancakeswap

I am trying to exchange 1 USDT for some BNB. By using PancakeSwap Smart Router V3 and python web3.

example code

```
tokenOut = web3.to_checksum_address("0x1d2f0da169ceb9fc7b3144628db156f3f6c60dbe") # XRP
tokenIn = web3.to_checksum_address("0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955") # USDT
weth = web3.to_checksum_address("0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c") # weth
fee = 4000
recipient = wallet 
deadline = int(time.time() + 6000)
qty = Wei(10**18) 
min_tokens_bought = 0

tx = pancake_smart_router_contract.functions.exactInputSingle(
       ( 
            tokenIn, 
            weth, 
            fee, 
            recipient, 
            deadline, 
            qty,
            min_tokens_bought, 
            0
        )
        )

tx_params: TxParams = {
        "from": wallet_addr,
        "gas": Wei(250_000),
        "gasPrice": web3.eth.gas_price,
        "value": Wei(0), 
        "nonce": web3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet)
        } 

        
transaction = tx.build_transaction(tx_params)

signed_transaction = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
        transaction, 
        private_key=private_key
        )

a = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(
        signed_transaction.rawTransaction
        )
```

However i am getting error in blockchain.

**You can view the transaction in detail here**

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x0a7c4d902f62e19f3d3f0581580a4bfcec48a17c99945da87442affdcad2c62e

[image]
**Please help me what am I doing wrong? I also have problems with the estimate_gas function for this exchange. If you have developed similar functionality please share the correct usage code.**

Comment: Did you approve the Router V3 contract to be able to spend your WETH? this is required first

Comment: Yes, I approve the Router V3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see on my github here https://github.com/ylasgamers/web3.eth.py/tree/main/DEX maybe help

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
import json
import logging
import datetime 
import threading
import asyncio
import requests
import time
import os
import sys
import ctypes
import pyperclip as pc

#bsc = "https://bsc-rpc.gateway.pokt.network" #rpc bsc custom #you can find rpc on chainlist.org
inputrpc = str(input("Input Url RPC/Node Blockchain Network : "))
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(inputrpc))
#chainId = 56 #you can find chainid on chainlist.org
chainId = int(input("Input Chain ID Blockchain Network : "))

ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW("Swap Buy On DEX PancakeSwap V3")
print('')
print('Swap Buy On DEX PancakeSwap V3 With Auto Slippage')
print('This Support Ethereum, Binance Smart Chain, Polygon zkEVM, Linea & Base')
print('')

#connecting web3
if  web3.isConnected() == True:
    print("Web3 Connected...\n")
else :
    print("Error Connecting Please Try Again...")

sender = web3.toChecksumAddress(input("Enter Your Address 0x...: "))
#sender = web3.toChecksumAddress('0x0') #send from this address
senderkey = input("Enter Your Privatekey abcde12345...: ")
#senderkey = 'abcd1234' #senderkey
tokenaddr = web3.toChecksumAddress(input('Enter Token Address 0x...: '))
contract_router = web3.toChecksumAddress(input("Enter Contract Address Router DEX : "))
#gasAmount = 300000 #gas limit // change if transaction fail
#gasPrice = 1 #gas price
#chainId = 56 

router_abi = json.loads('[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_factoryV2","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_deployer","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_factoryV3","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_positionManager","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_stableFactory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_stableInfo","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_WETH9","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"factory","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"info","type":"address"}],"name":"SetStableSwap","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"WETH9","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"}],"name":"approveMax","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"}],"name":"approveMaxMinusOne","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"}],"name":"approveZeroThenMax","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"}],"name":"approveZeroThenMaxMinusOne","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"callPositionManager","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"result","type":"bytes"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"paths","type":"bytes[]"},{"internalType":"uint128[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint128[]"},{"internalType":"uint24","name":"maximumTickDivergence","type":"uint24"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"secondsAgo","type":"uint32"}],"name":"checkOracleSlippage","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"path","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"uint24","name":"maximumTickDivergence","type":"uint24"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"secondsAgo","type":"uint32"}],"name":"checkOracleSlippage","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"deployer","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"path","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMinimum","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct IV3SwapRouter.ExactInputParams","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"name":"exactInput","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenIn","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenOut","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint24","name":"fee","type":"uint24"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMinimum","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceLimitX96","type":"uint160"}],"internalType":"struct IV3SwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"name":"exactInputSingle","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"flag","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"}],"name":"exactInputStableSwap","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"path","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMaximum","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct IV3SwapRouter.ExactOutputParams","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"name":"exactOutput","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenIn","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenOut","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint24","name":"fee","type":"uint24"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMaximum","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceLimitX96","type":"uint160"}],"internalType":"struct IV3SwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"name":"exactOutputSingle","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"flag","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"}],"name":"exactOutputStableSwap","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"factory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"factoryV2","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getApprovalType","outputs":[{"internalType":"enum IApproveAndCall.ApprovalType","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token0","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"token1","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0Min","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1Min","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct IApproveAndCall.IncreaseLiquidityParams","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"name":"increaseLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"result","type":"bytes"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token0","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"token1","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint24","name":"fee","type":"uint24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0Min","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1Min","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"}],"internalType":"struct IApproveAndCall.MintParams","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"result","type":"bytes"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"previousBlockhash","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"data","type":"bytes[]"}],"name":"multicall","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"","type":"bytes[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"data","type":"bytes[]"}],"name":"multicall","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"","type":"bytes[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"data","type":"bytes[]"}],"name":"multicall","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"results","type":"bytes[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount0Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount1Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"pancakeV3SwapCallback","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"positionManager","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"pull","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"refundETH","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"selfPermit","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"expiry","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"selfPermitAllowed","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"expiry","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"selfPermitAllowedIfNecessary","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"selfPermitIfNecessary","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_info","type":"address"}],"name":"setStableSwap","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"stableSwapFactory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"stableSwapInfo","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountMinimum","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"}],"name":"sweepToken","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountMinimum","type":"uint256"}],"name":"sweepToken","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountMinimum","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeBips","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"feeRecipient","type":"address"}],"name":"sweepTokenWithFee","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountMinimum","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeBips","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"feeRecipient","type":"address"}],"name":"sweepTokenWithFee","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountMinimum","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"}],"name":"unwrapWETH9","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountMinimum","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeBips","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"feeRecipient","type":"address"}],"name":"unwrapWETH9WithFee","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountMinimum","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeBips","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"feeRecipient","type":"address"}],"name":"unwrapWETH9WithFee","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"wrapETH","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]')
tokenabi = json.loads('[{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"_decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"_name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"_symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"subtractedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"decreaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getOwner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"addedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]')
contractrouter = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_router, abi=router_abi)
token_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=tokenaddr, abi=tokenabi)
tokenName = token_contract.functions.name().call()
tokenSymbol = token_contract.functions.symbol().call()
wrapped = contractrouter.functions.WETH9().call()
contractwrapped = web3.eth.contract(address=wrapped, abi=tokenabi)

#Get balance account
print('')
def UpdateBalance():
    balance = web3.eth.get_balance(sender)
    balance_bnb = web3.fromWei(balance,'ether')
    print('Your Balance' ,balance_bnb, 'BNB')
    #Get token balance account
    token_balance = token_contract.functions.balanceOf(sender).call()
    balance_token = web3.fromWei(token_balance, 'ether')
    print('Token Balance' ,balance_token, tokenSymbol)
    
UpdateBalance()

print('')
inputamount = float(input("Enter Amount Of You Want To Buy [ETH/BNB/MATIC/OTHER] : ")) #ex 1 / 0.1 / 0.001 / 0.0001 / 0.00001
amount = web3.toWei(float(inputamount), 'ether')
deadline = int(time.time()) + 1000000
        
#estimate gas limit approve
gas_approve = contractwrapped.functions.approve(contract_router, amount).buildTransaction({
    'chainId': chainId,
    'from': sender,
    'gasPrice': web3.eth.gas_price, #web3.toWei(gasPrice,'gwei'),
    'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender)
})
gasApprove = web3.eth.estimateGas(gas_approve)

#calculate transaction fee
print('')
print('Processing Approve Spender WBNB...')
gasPrice = web3.fromWei(web3.eth.gas_price, 'gwei')
Caclfee = web3.fromWei(gasPrice*gasApprove, 'gwei')
print('Transaction Fee :' ,Caclfee, 'ETH/BNB/MATIC/OTHER')

#Approve
Approve = contractwrapped.functions.approve(contract_router, amount).buildTransaction({
    'chainId': chainId,
    'from': sender,
    'gas': gasApprove,
    'gasPrice': web3.eth.gas_price, #web3.toWei(gasPrice,'gwei'),
    'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender)
})

sign_approve = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(Approve, senderkey)
web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(sign_approve.rawTransaction)
print('Approved Spender Token Wait 10 Second...')
time.sleep(10)
print('')  

#estimate gas limit contract
gas_tx = contractrouter.functions.exactInputSingle((wrapped, tokenaddr, 500, sender, amount, 0, 0)).buildTransaction({
    'chainId': chainId,
    'from': sender,
    'value': amount,
    'gasPrice': web3.eth.gas_price, #web3.toWei(gasPrice,'gwei'),
    'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender)
})
gasAmount = web3.eth.estimate_gas(gas_tx)

#calculate transaction fee
print('')
amountFromWei = web3.fromWei(amount, 'ether')
gasPrice = web3.fromWei(web3.eth.gas_price, 'gwei')
Caclfee = web3.fromWei(gasPrice*gasAmount, 'gwei')
print('Transaction Fee :' ,Caclfee, 'ETH/BNB/MATIC/OTHER')
print('Processing Swap Buy :' ,amountFromWei, 'ETH/BNB/MATIC/OTHER FOR TOKEN' ,tokenName)

token_tx = contractrouter.functions.exactInputSingle((wrapped, tokenaddr, 500, sender, amount, 0, 0)).buildTransaction({
    'chainId': chainId,
    'from': sender,
    'value': amount,
    'gas': gasAmount,
    'gasPrice': web3.eth.gas_price, #web3.toWei(gasPrice,'gwei'),
    'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender)
})

#sign the transaction
sign_txn = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(token_tx, senderkey)
#send transaction
tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(sign_txn.rawTransaction)

#get transaction hash
txid = str(web3.toHex(tx_hash))
print('')
print('Transaction Success TX-ID Copied To Clipboard')
print(txid)
pc.copy(txid)
print('Update Current Balance In 30 Second...')
time.sleep(30)
print('')
UpdateBalance() #get latest balance
print('Will Close Automatically In 30 Second...')
time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).